# Any javascript library to create an image gallery for android and iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, gallery

Actually I'm using [touch gallery](http://neteye.github.com/touch-gallery.html) but It doen't work in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sencha touch.

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

in kitchen sink demo you can find a carousel

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

User Interface > Carousel widget will work in both android and iphone.

I know it is not a lightweight solution but sencha is a nice library that deserves a try